# Create list of lists and add to dictionary in for Loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I want to create a loop to generate a dictionary with for each key 5 lists with each three values. And add edit the last value of list 2 and 3 based on the key of the dictionary and the index of the list (so list 2 and 3).

I tried the following code but get the error message: 'cannot unpack non-iterable int object'

```
# Create dicitonairy with 6 empty lists
dict_of_lists = dict.fromkeys(range(0,6),[])
for key, value in dict_of_lists:
    # Create 5 lists with the list number as the first value
    for li in range(5):
        dict_of_lists[key] = [li,0,0]
    # Edit the last value of list 1 and 2 (index)
    for wi in [1,2]:
        dict_of_lists[wi][2] = item[wi]*price[key]
```

What is the best way to create the following output:

```
{
0:[[0,0,0],[1,0,x],[2,0,x],[3,0,0],[4,0,0]]
1:[[0,0,0],[1,0,x],[2,0,x],[3,0,0],[4,0,0]]
2:[[0,0,0],[1,0,x],[2,0,x],[3,0,0],[4,0,0]]
3:[[0,0,0],[1,0,x],[2,0,x],[3,0,0],[4,0,0]]
4:[[0,0,0],[1,0,x],[2,0,x],[3,0,0],[4,0,0]]
5:[[0,0,0],[1,0,x],[2,0,x],[3,0,0],[4,0,0]]
}
```

Where x is a value based on the list where it's in (1 to 5) and the key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through a dict wrongly. If you want to iterate with both `key` and `value` specified inside the loop (like in yours), you should iterate through dict items, because a usual iteration iterates through dict keys. So you should change your line to:

`for key, value in dict_of_lists.items():`

*(PS: There are unspecified `item` and `price` in the last line, I suppose you specified them before this block)*

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_of_lists = dict.fromkeys(range(0,6),[])
for key, value in dict_of_lists.items():
    # Create 5 lists with the list number as the first value
    l = []
    for li in range(5):
        if li == 1 or li == 2:
            # l.append([li, 0, li*key]) 
            l.append([li, 0, 'x'])
        else:
            l.append([li,0,0])
    dict_of_lists[key] = l
print (dict_of_lists)
```

output:

```
{0: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 'x'], [2, 0, 'x'], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]], 
1: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 'x'], [2, 0, 'x'], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]], 
2: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 'x'], [2, 0, 'x'], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]], 
3: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 'x'], [2, 0, 'x'], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]], 
4: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 'x'], [2, 0, 'x'], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]], 
5: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 'x'], [2, 0, 'x'], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over a dictionary you need to use `dict.items()`.

In your case:

```
for key, value in dict_of_lists.items():
    #code
```